# Unity SetActive() doesn't activate object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a problem that I can't solve by my self.

I have a Pause Button which need to activate pause panel on scene, but nothing work.
1. I have a public GO "Panel" attached in the inspector.
2.Inspector writes that: "There is no 'GameObject' attached to the "Panel" game object, but a script is trying to access it."
3.Script on always active GO.
4.At start Panel is Active.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Scene ActiveScene;
    private GameController gm;
    public GameObject panel;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
    gm = GetComponent<GameController>();
    ActiveScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        panel.SetActive(false);

    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        Debug.Log("Pause");
        panel.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }

    public void Menu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(ActiveScene.buildIndex);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            panel.SetActive(false);
    }
```

Glad if u can help!

Comment: Do this question in Game Development of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you, done!

Comment: @AAShakil: Please, stop redirecting people on Game Development for any question about Unity. It is absolutely legit to ask here, if they're about programming.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー I was trying to help him to get better answer.

Comment: @AAShakil GameDev SE actually has *less* traffic than the [unity3d] tag on SO. Plus, crossposting the question on Game Dev and SO is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: I attached the script twice.